# VBA Excel Loop writs data; Access VBA Loop reads data - VBA.CreateObject Error

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ms-access, simultaneous

I wrote a Loop in Excel to gather data via send keys from 3rd party apps every couple seconds (works well) and save them in several `xlsx` files, and another Loop in Access DB to read some of these files every couple seconds to update DB.

The problem is if I run these macros on one PC- at some point (unpredictable, difficult to reproduce) I will get an error in Excel VBA related to

```
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
....
Call fso.CopyFile(Pfad, Ziel, True)
```

Basically, Excel deletes then the file it's supposed to replace but doesn't replace it. 
This also happens if the `fso.copyfile` is totally unrelated to the one Access is trying to read.
- Therefore I guess its a basic problem of the methods I am using in Access+Excel in combination.

Is there a way to make the Access reading less "invasiv" so it doesn't disturb if Excel is using the `fso = VBA.CreateObject` at the exact moment?

Here is the area of the Excel VBA which results sometimes in Error 
(Supposedly if Access is doing something invasive in exact same moment)

[image]

Here is the relevant Access Code:

[image]

I don't have the error code at the moment, will add that as soon as it's happening again.

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give other applications time to do their work by adding a `DoEvents` to your loop in the access side code.

Comment: Ah that sounds good,...will give it a try next week,...thanks

Comment: adding doevents in Access sadly didnt work (at the end I added doevents pretty much everywhere, but without any effect) - I am not at work atm, end of next week I ll change access so it first creates a copy of the file then reads the copy and hope that will solve the problem (or at least reduces potential probs)

Comment: Also I remember the error code from Excel VBA (Runtime Error 70 ... guess because the file copy/paste method got somehow interrupted and so there was no file)